# Критическая ошибка в плагине Custom Routes

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

На сайте было настроено автоматическое добавление статей (статьи генерировал какой-то скрипт и отправлял их по API скорее всего на сайт), недавно статьи перестали добавляться и на странице Custom Routes, который судя по всему был сделан, чтобы добавить API для добавления статей (могу ошибаться), стала выводиться следующая ошибка (рис. 1). И так на всех страницах, никаких логов не удалось найти. Может не там искал, но debug.log не сгенерировался даже.

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true); // не помогает получить код ошибки, к сожалению.
```

Полный список плагинов ниже, так как, возможно, я перепутал вообще и ищу проблему в другом месте.

1. Advanced Custom Routes - Custom Endpoints for WP REST API
2. Change wp-admin login
3. Clearfy Pro
4. Insert Headers and Footers
5. JSON Basic Authentication
6. Redirection
7. Simple Local Avatars
8. WordPress REST API Authentication
9. WP Realtime Sitemap
10. WP REST API Controller

Cкрипта, который добавлял статьи найти на сервере не могу, возможно, он скомпилирован в бинарник либо вообще на другом сервере расположен, раз зачем-то добавили Custom Routes.

Также некоторые из плагинов требуют обновления, как и сам WordPress, но так как у меня минимальный опыт работы с ним, то обновляться хотелось бы в последнюю очередь.

В общем, что можно сделать и куда копать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы дали неплохое описание, но вряд ли вам смогут помочь. На сайт ряд устаревших плагинов (например, WP REST API Controller давно уже не нужен, функционал в ядре WordPress). Сообщения об ошибке нет. Да если бы и была - нужна отладка непосредственно на сайте. Наймите специалиста, который может это сделать.

Comment: И вообще, по списку плагинов - всё очень старое, надо кардинально переделывать сайт.

Comment: Вероятнее всего именно потому, что какой-то умный человек что-то обновил или неведомый, старый плагин перестал функционировать у Вас и проблема. Опять же, могли обновить хостинг и перестало поддерживаться например CURL или ещё что из старого в PHP (не про курл)... Как выше написали, без копания с микроскопом не обойтись. Поскольку это долгий, нудный процесс, бесплатно вряд-ли кто согласиться, а если согласиться, огребёте ещё больше проблем в будущем. Далее, тут же пишется -сама ошибка в почте.

Comment: А вообще >"статьи генерировал какой-то скрипт и отправлял их по API скорее всего на сайт", какой-то и скорее всего - много допущений, Вы хоть в functions.php заглядывали? Может там есть ответ? А ещё есть не шуточная тревога за безопасность, поскольку так много дырявых плагинов позволяющих управлять сайтом удалённо, что волосы дыбом. А относительно плагинов, то надо смотреть настройки и что/кто их использует.